# Function to get variable content and strip variable to only return numbers

Tags: php, woocommerce, preg-replace

Attempting to extract the shipping tracking number from the content of a Woocommerce note to customer to eventually pass to a custom field as a value

Original function

```
    function get_value( $comment, $parameters ) {
    return $comment->content;
}
```

Modified function (not working)

```
function get_value( $comment, $parameters ) {
    $tracking_note = $comment->content;
    $new_output = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $tracking_note );
    return $new_output->content;
    
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that preg_replace returns an object? Have you tried to visit php.net to read function description?

Comment: The function can just return the variable like: `return $new_output;`. Would that work?

Comment: @GerarddeVisser Thanks, thats all I needed.

Comment: @user2059376 Great this works. I've added this as an answer for future reference for others looking for this solution. Feel free to accept / upvote the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

preg_replace will not return an object, also refer to: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php.

Just return the variable like: `return $new_output;`